Viability of redundant checks
I have a system for friendships and friendRequests on my backend. Friend requests CANNOT be made if there is already a friendship between the supplied users.
Because of this restriction in making friend requests, it would be redundant to check if that friendship already exists upon hitting the /friendRequest/accept resource, because it is expected that if a friendRequest exists, there is not a friendship between the users. What are your thoughts on this? Would you include a check for an existing friendship in the /friendRequest/accept resource?
Normally I would not include a check, but as this is my first time writing production-ready code, I want to be thorough. Thanks!

How sure are you that multiple requests were not sent before one was accepted? Are there any other scenarios that could result in a Request existing while the Friendship also exists? How expensive is the check to ensure you are not accepting a request for a friendship that already exists?  In my experience, it has always been beneficial to pay for this check, rather than to deal with the potential fallout of not handling a situation you could have anticipated.
